# Trim comboBox with non fixed number

Tags: c#

I have this comboBox:

```
A6 - "Sometext"
A79 - "Sometext"
B6789- "Sometext"
B69679 - "Sometext"
C67 - "Sometext"
D - "Sometext"
D11 - "Sometext"
```

How I could show the selectedItem into textBox with only the strings A6, A79, B6789... without the "Sometext" ??

I used this when working on a fixed number of char:

```
string temp = comboBox1.Text;
char[] array1 = temp.ToCharArray();
textBox1.Text = "" + array1[0] + array1[1];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text.Split('-').First().Trim();
```